# SQL Server Profiler - Column Meanings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

Can anyone point to a reference which describes what is being returned in the IntegerData and IntegerData2 columns. I am particularly interested in their meaning for SQL:StmtCompleted event.

Answer (score 2):

It varies by event. See here for SQL:StmtCompleted:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`IntegerData` returns the *actual* number of rows returned by the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the [`SQL:StmtCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189886.aspx) MSDN documentation:

```
IntegerData   int    Number of rows returned by the statement.
IntegerData2  int    End offset (in bytes) of the statement that is being executed.
```

There are similar specifications for almost all other profiler events, under the [SQL Server Event Class Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175481.aspx) MSDN chapter.